# Div Close and open with delay function of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a advertisement Box, as show here http://jsfiddle.net/TFeXY/1/ ,

when user click on button 'Show Ads', 'addBox' get open and he can close 'addBox' div by clicking 'close' button . this all work properly.

but when an user click on close button of 'addbox'  before 10 second (say after 3 sec), and  click on 'Show Ads' button , 'addBox' doesn't get open instantly . How can i make 'addBox' visible instantly .

here is html portion,

```
<div id ="addBox" style ="display:none; height:200px; width:200p x; background:red">
    advertisment popup
    <a id ="Close" syle="float:right;">Close</a>
</div>

<a id="ShowAds">Show Ads</a>
```

and jQuery portion :

```
$('#ShowAds').click(function(){
$('#addBox').show(100).delay(10000).hide(100);
})

$('#Close').click(function(){
$('#addBox').hide();
})
```

Comment: Change the close click handler to: `$('#addBox').stop().hide();`

Comment: Dude, why are you using 'delay(10000).hide(100);' can you please tell me the intention behind this?

Comment: Was one of the answers helpful? If so please accept it.

Answer (score 3):

use `stop()`..

```
 $('#clickme').click(function () {
   $('#addBox').show(100).delay(6000).hide(100);
 })

$('#Close').click(function () {
    $('#addBox').stop().hide();
})
```

however... i have a look to native  [setTimeout function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.setTimeout) too. you can cleartimeout by using

```
clearTimeout();
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/TFeXY/3/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.stop` on the `#clickme`:

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/J4s4A/)**

```
$('#addBox').stop().show(100).delay(6000).hide(100);
```